# jquery animate() method is not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".first").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      'font-size': '20px',
      'margin-top': '12px',
      'font-weight': '600'
    }, 500)
  })
})
```

```css
.first {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="first">Hello</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to animate a text using jquery animate() method. But the animation is not smooth. I have tried to delay the animation and also use transition attribute in css, but the result is the same. What should I do to make the animation smooth?

Comment: I think it's smooth enough! what do you expect anymore?

Comment: you can achieve this without jquery animate function. Use css `transition` property and apply same style on `hover`.

Answer (score -1):

when you want to use `animate.css` you should use attributes in it's right way, for example in **CSS** `margin-top: 20px` is working BUT in **css.animate** it's not working and you should write like this `marginTop: '20px'`.
**NOTE:**
in animate.css you **SHOULD NOT** use "" or '' in attribute name and just use this in values.

so you should use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".first").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      fontSize: '20px',
      marginTop: '12px',
      fontWeight: '600'
    }, 500)
  })
})
```

this this is your code working. [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u6c9yk8/)

Comment: @Pedram in css.animate you should use attributes in it's way, for example in css `margin-top: 20px` working but in css.animate this is not working and you should write it like this `marginTop: '20px'`.

Comment: Still the animation is not smooth!